# Python: find common letters in array without cutting a word

Tags: python

Here's my (working) code:

```
groupes = [{'description': 'i am a letter', 'exemple': 'e1'},
           {'description': 'i am a brick', 'exemple': 'e2'},
           {'description': 'i am a dog', 'exemple': 'e3'}]
d = zip(*[g['description'] for g in groupes])
b = []
for a in d:
    if len(set(a)) == 1:
        b.append(set(a).pop())
    else:
        break
a = u''.join(b)
l = len(a)
print()
b = [u'{} "{}"'.format(b['description'][l:], b['exemple']) for b in groupes]
b = u', '.join(b).strip()
print(u'{} ({})'.format(a, b))
```

It outputs all the letters in common, and with the reste, put it in `()` with the example.
My problem is when the letters in common stop in the middle of a word, like this:

```
groupes = [{'description': 'i am a douche', 'exemple': 'e1'},
           {'description': 'i am a dandy', 'exemple': 'e2'},
           {'description': 'i am a dog', 'exemple': 'e3'}]
```

Then you'll get:

```
i am a d (ouche "e1", andy "e2", og "e3")
```

Whereas I want to get

```
i am a (douche "e1", dandy "e2", dog "e3")
```

Any idea how to do this "the python way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add:

```
if any(' ' != c for c in next(d,[])):
    while b[-1] != ' ':
        b.pop()
```

after your `for` loop. This:

- checks if there are any characters in the next set of characters that aren't spaces. If there are, that means that there is at least one word being cut off
- pops any characters that arent spaces from the end of b
- if all 3 strings are identical, the `next()` would normally cause a `StopIteration` error so make sure to have the `[]` default

Also, you should change `print(u'{} ({})'.format(a, b))` to `print(u'{}({})'.format(a, b))` to avoid an extra space before the `(` in your printed string.

## EDIT - better way?

A possibly more pythonic way than this is to change your `zip` to this:

```
d = zip(*[g['description'].split() for g in groupes])
```

to split each string and instead iterate word by word instead of interating by letter.

Just make sure to change your `join` as well to:

```
a = u' '.join(b) #space instead of empty string
```

## EDIT - why the `*` star?

This is used for argument unpacking. Notice the difference between passing a list (or in most cases, any iterable) with and without the *:

```
>>> def foo(a= None, b = None, c = None):
    print('''
    a: %s
    b: %s
    c: %s
    ''' %(str(a),str(b),str(c)))


>>> test = [1,2,3]
>>> foo(test)

    a: [1, 2, 3]
    b: None
    c: None

>>> foo(*test)

    a: 1
    b: 2
    c: 3
```

Comment: With your second solution if I try with "pelh" and "help" then set('pehl')==set('help') then I may get "true" even though the words are not the same. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but remember that you are calling `set` on the object being returned from `zip`. So say your descriptions are `"help"` and `"hepl'`, then `set(a)` in your code is equivalent to `set(('help','hepl'))` which would still give you a length of 2 since `'help' != 'hepl'`

Comment: in other words, it would still work; I have tried and tested it :)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, it works flawlessly. I could not google for **`*`**, may I ask you why I had to add a star here: "`d = zip(*[g.description.split() for g in groupes])`"? (I did this code based on some sample but if you google for `python what means *` you dont get a valid result)

Comment: I think I'll give this exercice for my students, to do this in Php + command line, then I'll show them my solution in Python **`:^D`**

Comment: the `*` unpacks the list from the list comprehension into separate arguments in the function. I will edit to show an example.